# Giving unexpected token in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am new to Nodejs. I am using Eclipse IDE(added node plugin) to write Nodejs code.

I wrote simple logic for addition of two numbers.

```
const s= (num1,num2) => num1 + num2;
```

I am getting error stating --**Syntax error on token ">" remove token**.
I am using Nodejs verion v 9.8.0 . Can any one suggest me what I have to do to resolve this?

Comment: Install visual studio code. It is lightweight and supports js syntax out of the box.

Comment: Are you getting an actual syntax error when you execute it, or just from the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, the error that you got is due to your IDE as there is no syntax error. If you copy and paste in the chrome console, it works